# unexpected behaviour in Appium

Tags: selenium, testng, appium

I am new in appium. I am running following test for IOS

```
@Test
public void Login() throws InterruptedException{
Thread.sleep(3000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//window[1]/textfield[9]")).sendKeys("john");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//window[1]/secure[1]")).sendKeys("asdf1234");
driver.findElement(By.name("btn checkbox")).click();

driver.findElement(By.name("Login")).click();

Thread.sleep(6000);
```

here it works fine, it logins, but when I comment `driver.findElement(By.name("btn checkbox")).click();` this line it does not login, but shows test is passed, there is no single exception
please can anybody tell me what is problem here?

Comment: What is this btn checkbox doing?

Comment: its clicking on checkbox of "Remember me" 
driver.findElement(By.name("btn checkbox")).click(); this line is generated by appium

Comment: Put code in try - catch blocks and check if any exception it catches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your test doesn't check if it's logged in or not. You're performing the actions to make it login, but you're not actually validating anything. You're smoke testing.

What you want to do here...

- Build something that lets you check for any indicator that you have finished the login process. (like welcome label!)
- **Use [an explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) to do this**.
- Define your success criteria. Login usually takes 10 seconds. Our success criteria may be anything under 25 seconds.
- If it doesn't find the element after 25 seconds in the exception that's thrown (TimeoutException), you should return something like "None", else return the element.

Should look something like this:

`WebElement welcomeLabel = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 25))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("welcomeLabel")));`

And then you'll say something like this:
`Assert.assertIsNotNone(welcomeLabel)` **this assertion is what makes this NOT a smoke test**

Comment: I wouldn't say a test without assertions is a smoke test. A (smoke) test without assertions isn't a test at all.

Answer (score 1):

Of course that's happening. The only thing you do is clicking on that button. Appium is doing exactly that, doesn't encounter any problem, and returns a 'test passed'.

You have to write some kind of a test yourself, to know if you're logged in or not.

For example by searching for a logout button at the next page.

Example:

```
Assert.assertTrue(wd.findElement(By.name("Logout")).isDisplayed());
```